# last element in list using ocaml List.fold_left

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I can find the last element of a list by the following code.

```
let last (xs:'a list) : 'a =
    let rec aux xs prev =
        match xs with
        | [] -> prev
        | x::ys -> aux ys x in
    match xs with
    | [] -> failwith "no element"
    | x::xs -> aux xs x
```

How do I find the last element of the same list using the `List.fold_left` function in OCaml?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fold_left` accesses the list from the head to the tail, thus the function passed to `fold_left` should just replace the accumulator with the current element of the list. Thus simply,

```
let last = function
  | x::xs -> List.fold_left (fun _ y -> y) x xs
  | []    -> failwith "no element"
```

You can write your function directly, without the `aux` function.

```
let rec last = function
  | x::[] -> x
  | _::xs -> last xs
  | []    -> failwith "no element"
```