# Understanding Fold_Left in Ocaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, fold

I have been trying to get the last item in a list in Ocaml. 
This is what I tried.

```
let last2 (xs:'a list) : 'a =
    List.fold_left (fun acc element -> let acc=element) acc xs;;
```

But it didn't work. My idea is that acc will be element till the last item in the list. And return acc after reaching the end of the list will give me the last item in the list.

Could someone help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am getting close with the following

```
let last2 (xs:'a list) : 'a =
    List.fold_left (fun a b -> b) 1 xs;;
```

However, I can only use last2 on a integer list. A polymorphic last2 will be better.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699256/last-element-in-list-using-ocaml-list-fold-left

Comment: In `last2`, using `1` tells the type checker that the functions accumulator is an integer. Since the function returns elements of the list, the list must also be integers. You should either 1) use an option as in, `List.fold_left (fun _ b -> Some b) None xs`, or do what was done in the answer mentioned by virgile where we use the first element of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but your syntax for expressing it is wrong. This function:

```
# fun acc element -> let acc = element;;
Error: Syntax error
```

Isn't correct (as you've probably noticed).

To define a function that returns a value `expr`:

```
fun a b -> <expr>
```

Your expression should have the value `b`. So your function would look like this:

```
fun a b -> b
```

(With possible renamings.)

Another way to look at your problem is that when you use `let` as an expression, it needs an `in`. So you could write the function like this (though it's redundant):

```
fun a b -> let a = b in a
```

However, this form seems to be a result of thinking imperatively. You're not assigning a new value to `a`. You're just returning a value.

The following function is completely identical; it just renames the second `a` to something else:

```
fun a b -> let zzz = b in zzz
```

Generally speaking in OCaml you want to give up the idea of assigning values to variables. They are immutable and can't change value (generally speaking).

**Update**

Here's a session showing that `fun a b -> b` will solve the problem.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# List.fold_left (fun a b -> b) 0 [2; 3; 4; 88];;
- : int = 88
```

One thing that's easy to forget is that you need to supply a starting value for the accumulator. One obvious choice is the first element of the list. (There must be a first element; an empty list doesn't *have* a last element.)

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I understand your explanation on expression but I tried (fun acc element -> element) earlier and it didn't work. I think fold_left will continue to the last element in the list, thus I was hoping that at each "stage", I can update the acc to the element.

Comment: I'm not sure why you had a problem, but `fun a b -> b` does work. I've updated my answer to show a working session.

Comment: @boxme, Whatever the function returns will be the `acc` in the next step. You don't need to explicitly update it.